# Problema na exibição da MATRIZ em C

Tags: c

Olá, gostaria de ajuda pra tentar resolver o problema de uma matriz do meu programa em C. Foi criado a matriz dizendo que ela devia estar preenchida com tal caractere, ela até funciona, mas a última linha sempre não é exibido o caractere que foi definido, e não importa quantas linhas e quantas colunas eu coloque sempre acontece a mesma coisa.
Já li e reli todo o código mas não encontrei nada anormal.
pensei que era overflow mas pelo pouco conhecimento que tenho overflow não ocorre em variável do tipo CHAR. Desculpem se eu estiver errado

### Seguem os blocos do código:

DECLARAÇÕES E BIBLIOTECAS:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define COL 7
#define ROW 4
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

void inicializa(char matriz[ROW][COL]);
void mostrarPainel(char matriz[ROW][COL]);
void comprar(char matriz[ROW][COL]);
void reservar(char matriz[ROW][COL]);
void legenda();
int menuOpcao();
int colunaY();
int linhaX();
```

---

SWITCH DO MENU:

```
inicializa(matriz); //Iniciliza a matriz com valores .(Livre)

  do{
     system("cls");//Limpa a tela                
     opcao=menuOpcao();                   
     switch(opcao){
        case 1:
          system("cls");
          system("cls"); 
          mostrarPainel(matriz);//Mostra o Painel atualizado
          comprar(matriz); // Realiza a compra de uma cadeira no painel, marcando c/ um X
          break;

        case 2:
          system("cls");
          system("cls");
          mostrarPainel(matriz);
          reservar(matriz); //Realiza a reserva de uma cadeira no painel, marcando c/ um R
          break;

        case 3:
          system("cls");
          mostrarPainel(matriz);
          getch();
          break;   

        case 4:
          loopContinue = FALSE; //condicao para saída do programa
     }
  }while(loopContinue);

  getchar();    
  return 0;       
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void inicializa(char matriz[ROW][COL]){
     int i,j;
     for(i=1;i<=ROW;i++)
       for(j=1;j<=COL;j++)
          matriz[i][j] = '.';
}

void mostrarPainel(char matriz[ROW][COL]){

  int i,j;
  printf("\n\n         %c   PAINEL DE OCUPACOES   %c\n\n",16,17);
  printf("          ");

  for(i=1;i<=COL;i++)
    printf("%d     ",i);

  for(i=1;i<=ROW;i++){
     printf("\n\n     %d",i);
     for(j=1;j<=COL;j++)
       printf("   (%c)",matriz[i][j]);     
  }
  //apresenta o menu na tela
  legenda();
}        
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Em C (e na grande maiorias das linguagens) os arrays (vetores são arrays unidimensionais e matrizes são arrays multidimensionais como você deve conhecer) tem índices que vão de 0 (zero) ate n-1 (onde n é o tamanho do array) ou seja, sua matriz tem os índices de maneira semelhantes, logo quando você for fazer seu for para percorrer a matriz você teria de ir de 0 ate COLS/ROWS -1, podendo fazer simplesmente assim:

```
void mostrarPainel(char matriz[ROW][COL]){

int i,j;
printf("\n\n %c PAINEL DE OCUPACOES %c\n\n",16,17);
printf(" ");

for(i=0;i<COL;i++){
    printf("%d ",i);
}

for(i=0;i<ROW;i++) {
    printf("\n\n %d",i); 
    for(j=1;j<=COL;j++) {
         printf(" (%c)",matriz[i][j]);
    }
} //apresenta o menu na tela legenda();
}
```